# Liu's new sieve weight

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Does Liu's sieve weight (in his arXiv paper ["On the gap between primes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.03681))
$$sieve(n)=(\sum_{\substack{d_i\mid (n-h_i),i=1,\cdots,k\\   (d_1,\cdots,d_k)\in\mathcal{D}}}\lambda_{d_1,\cdots,d_k} )^2$$
with
$$\mathcal{D}=\Big\{(d_1,\cdots,d_k)\in(0,N^{0.25-\varepsilon})^k\mid d_1\cdots d_k<\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    N^{0.25-\varepsilon}, & \hbox{$\exists i:$ $d_i=1$;} \\
    N^{0.5-\varepsilon}, & \hbox{$\forall i:$ $d_i\neq1$.}
  \end{array}
\right.\Big\}$$
conflict with the use of B-V theorem when applying the GPY method to study the gap between primes?